# Set the Default Date of SilverLight Date Picker to Current Date

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, date, datepicker

I have a Silverlight `Datagrid` in which one of the columns is a Date Column.

So i have used a `DataTemplateColumn` as Follows

```
 <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn   Header="Recieved Date" Width="Auto">
                        <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=RecievedDate, StringFormat='MM/dd/yyyy'}" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <sdk:DatePicker Name="dtpFinancialAndComplianceLog" Text="{Binding Path=RecievedDate, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                    </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

The problem is when i click on the `DatePicker` control the default date is set to 1/1/0001?

How can i set my datepicker to set to the current Date in Edit mode ?

I tried DisplayDateStart="{x:Static sys:DateTime.Now}" . But thats not working as Static only works works with WPF and doesnt work with Silverlight .

What would be the best way to set my datepicker to set to the current Date upon editing ?

Comment: If you omit `DisplayDate` doesn't the Silverlight datepicker default to today's date?

Comment: @paul Thanks ..Actually that was a typo.."Display date" was never there.It was one option that I tried ..Ive updated the question

Comment: Well, if you always want to start with todays date, you could try updating the direction of your binding to OneWay (i.e. no need for any binding code to try to set what starts off in the box)

Comment: See  if it helps : http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2009/10/05/refactor-silverlight-datepicker-to-show-current-day-text.aspx

Comment: @paul : Thanks so much.Your first comment was the key to the solution. I omitted Display date. Initially the DatePicker was bound to a DateTime Property. It had the initial value as 1/1/0001 . I changed that to string and since then datepicker default to today's date .  Ive changed the binding to Oneway too. Could you please mark this as an answer so that I can accept it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(from comments above to OP)

If you omit DisplayDate doesn't the Silverlight datepicker default to today's date?

Also, if you always want to start with todays date, you could try updating the direction of your binding to OneWay (i.e. no need for any binding code to try to set what starts off in the box)

Answer (score 0):

you may need to customize the DatePicker class by assigning current date in constructor of the DatePickerEX class which is derived from DatePicker